# Implementation of Multi-Threading and Multi-Processing using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing

I've defined a (test) Function in Python, which I am using to understand the different computation time that might be required to execute the code - using normal code (without using multi-processing or multi-threading), and then implementing each of them one by one.

Function (for Basic Usage):

```py
from random import randint as rInt

def highComputationFunction(rangeNumber):
    count_ = 0
    for i in range(rangeNumber):
        count_ = count_*2 + rInt(rangeNumber**2, rangeNumber**3)
    count_ = 10**100//count_

    return count_
```

Also, for Multi-Processing & Multi-Threading, I wanted to return the result of the thread to my Parent Function, so modified it like this:

```py
from random import randint as rInt

def highComputationFunction(rangeNumber, result):
    count_ = 0
    for i in range(rangeNumber):
        count_ = count_*2 + rInt(rangeNumber**2, rangeNumber**3)
    count_ = 10**100//count_

    return count_
```

Looking into the CPU Usage for each of the main function as below:

```py
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()
    rangeNumber = 10000
    coumputedNum = float(round(highComputationFunction(rangeNumber)//100**5000, 3))
    print('\tFunction of {} Executed in: {} seconds. Result = {}'.format(rangeNumber, round(time.time() - startTime, 2), coumputedNum))

    inTime = time.time()
    rangeNumber = 100000
    coumputedNum = float(round(highComputationFunction(rangeNumber)//100**5000, 3))
    print('\tFunction of {} Executed in: {} seconds. Result = {}'.format(rangeNumber, round(time.time() - inTime, 2), coumputedNum))

    inTime = time.time()
    rangeNumber = 1000000
    coumputedNum = float(round(highComputationFunction(rangeNumber)//100**5000, 3))
    print('\tFunction of {} Executed in: {} seconds. Result = {}'.format(rangeNumber, round(time.time() - inTime, 2), coumputedNum))

    print('Total Execution Time: {}'.format(round(time.time() - startTime, 2)))
```

This was executed in approximately 46 Seconds in Total. One output is as Below:

```py
    # python understandComputation.py
    #       Function of 10000 Executed in: 0.03 seconds. Result = 0.0
    #       Function of 100000 Executed in: 0.91 seconds. Result = 0.0
    #       Function of 1000000 Executed in: 45.49 seconds. Result = 0.0
    # Total Execution Time: 46.44
```

Executed the same thing with Multi-Threading:

```py
import time
import threading

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()
    result_ = 0
    threadList = []
    for i in [10000, 100000, 1000000]:
        curThread = threading.Thread(target = highComputationFunction, args = (i, result_))
        curThread.start()
        print('\tThread for {} Started.'.format(i))
        threadList.append(curThread)
        result_ += result_

    for i in threadList:
        i.join()

    print('Total Function Executed in: {} seconds. Result = {}'.format(round(time.time() - startTime, 2), result_))
```

For Multi-Processing:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()
    result_ = 0
    procList = []
    for i in [10000, 100000, 1000000]:
        curProc = multiprocessing.Process(target = highComputationFunction, args = (i, result_))
        curProc.start()
        print('\tProcess for {} Started.'.format(i))
        procList.append(curProc)
        result_ += result_

    for i in procList:
        i.join()

    print('Total Function Executed in: {} seconds. Result = {}'.format(round(time.time() - startTime, 2), result_))
```

Implementing this, got the output in much more time than usual.

```py
    # python understandComputation.py
    #       Thread for 10000 Started.
    #       Thread for 100000 Started.
    #       Thread for 1000000 Started.
    # Total Function Executed in: 47.04 seconds. Result = 0

    # python understandComputation.py
    #       Process for 10000 Started.
    #       Process for 100000 Started.
    #       Process for 1000000 Started.
    # Total Function Executed in: 47.21 seconds. Result = 0
```

Please tell me, if it is wrong with the implementation of the code or not. Expected result for multi-threading and multi-processing should be less than 45.5 Seconds, which is the maximum time taken for the execution of the 1000000  number in the actual code, but I'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: Re multithreading, google "Global Interpreter Lock".  Re multiprocessing, please show us your code (I can only see you threading code).

Comment: Please check. It is similar to multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks, @NPE understood the problem [from this Link](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Was wondering if you can point me to the right direction on applying Asynchronous function to pooling that returns a result from a function!